# What is the most forgiving data/field type settings in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, schema, full-text-indexing

I need to be able send some documents into Solr just to get something up and working... but be more controlled than using the "autoCreateFields" setting. I have 148 fields in my documents. With the auto-create functionality enabled about half the documents error when trying to be inserted.

I have tried StringField and text_general on all the fields ... and with that setting "on" 100% of the documents fail. So I am left wondering what the most accepting field would be? How can I get the process of inserting these documents figured out and then slowly come back and rework field types. I don't mind reinserting from scratch (blank core) each time I make an iteration.

I'm really new to the way fields are defined in Solr. So forgive if I use the wrong terminology.

Comment: When you say fail - what fails? What error message do you get? If you have a `string` or `text_general` field, it should allow almost any _valid_ textual content into them. But it does require the format to be in the correct encoding, so that it can be parsed as actual text. There is a BinaryField, but that content can't be queried - only stored.

Comment: Let me switch modes back and test that again.

Comment: what other properties should I include (not include) when setting all the fields via the API - tmpl = {stored: "true", indexed: "true", uninvertible: "true", name: key, type: "text_general"};

key variable is the name of the field I am putting in.

Comment: Still unsure of the safest way to go with those properties of text_general.... but seems like I was leaving off an id which if you turn off autoCreateFields looks like an issue. Still unsure of why when I let it run in that mode 50% fail. I thought just for an experiment I would try with 20 docs per payload thinking it would give it more data to analyze and make predictions about field type. Didn't seem to help and had more failures.

Comment: Please update your question with these details - it'll be easier to read than having them in the comments. `uninverted` shouldn't really matter for a text field as it can't have docValues anyway. But you'll have to add information about _what kind of failures_ you're having. Without that information it's hard to say anything useful. Every document needs to have an id, and the id needs to be unique (so if by chance your ids are being re-used, the later document will overwrite the first one). The schemaless mode adds a guid if an id isn't being supplied.

Comment: There is no such thing as "more data to analyze and predictions about field type" - the first time a field is submitted, the field type will be guessed based on the contents of the field type at that moment (since indexing can be a lossy process, you can't really re-do it later in an efficient way while still receiving documents). This is why schemaless mode works for experimenting, but for any production or seriouse use you should manually craft your schema to fit your application.

Comment: Doing continued work on this over next day. Will report back what I find - so many fields to deal with.. and the fields aren't related to anything I have done before (fintech). ID plus everything text_general at least is letting things flowing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure the `id` field is a `string` field - `text_general` will not work properly for that field. :-)

Comment: If your id is a uuid should you always use that type?

Comment: Sure, that would work. I don't think the difference to a plain string field will be very noticable.

Comment: One last follow up. If I understand correctly... been doing some more Solr reading. If I don't want to tokenize (take up more space) and just need the value, I should use string instead of text_general correct? Trying to optimize what I have setup now.

Comment: Correct, since you only need the value itself using `string` will be fine. If you don't need to query against the field either, you can also set `indexed="false"`.

Comment: You will still be able to find a non-indexed field via an exact match correct?

Comment: No, an unindexed field will not be searchable in any way. It generally means that it will only be stored (for example if you only want to use it in calculations). You can also set it as stored="false" and then use docValues.

Comment: Just a suggestion @MatsLindh ... but you could summarize some of your thoughts on the different properties of text_general and string ... and some of the properties you can tweak for an answer I can accept. For rep. Thank you so much for your feedback along this Solr journey of mine.